# Unusual partitioned matrix

Tags: matrices

Could anyone tell me the way the latex code producing a matrix partition whose form is the attached picture
[image]

Comment: I couldn't solve this code? I tried many times, I reviewed all the posts but couldn't find a similar one? any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 'matrix' library of TikZ is a general way https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Perhaps a Minimal Working Example (MWE) with what you have so far would help the community help you get the result you are seeking.

Comment: Do you also need the entries or just the lines?

Comment: Thank you all. It doesn't matter about the entries. I updated the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is two ways of doing that with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

For the first method, I have drawn all the rules with Tikz using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` (you need at least the version 5.11 of 2021-02-22).

For the second method, I have created blocks (with the built-in command `\Block`) and the key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \foreach \x in {3,...,7} 
         { \draw (\x-|1) -- (\x-|\inteval{\x+1}) 
                 (\x|-1) -- (\x|-\inteval{\x+1}) ; } ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\bigskip
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,hvlines]
\Block{2-2}{}1&2&\Block{2-1}{}3&\Block{3-1}{}4&\Block{4-1}{}5&\Block{5-1}{}6&\Block{6-1}{}7\\
             1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\Block{1-2}{}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\Block{1-3}{}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\Block{1-4}{}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\Block{1-5}{}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\Block{1-6}{}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is fascinating!  unfortunately, I have tried both but it couldn't work; I got an error!! I don't know why? Would you please guide me on how to avoid that? Another issue, is I need exactly what you have done BUT without partition the leading submatrix

Comment: I think you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation. If you use Overleaf, you can retrieve the latest version of that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty` and upload it in the repertory of your project in Overleaf.

Comment: Indeed, I don't have nicematrix packages at all! sorry for that I didn't know about such packages. It is ok. I am very thankful for your kindness. I got it. Regards

Comment: I have modified my answer in order to have an output exactly as requested.

Comment: Many thanks! you are really KIND. All respect.

Comment: Dear Mr. Pantigny, 

I tried your approach it works significantly, however, I need the whole matrix to be even x even rank (8x8). I tried to modify but I couldn't. Could you help me. Sorry if I disturb you.

Comment: You should modify the picture of your question because I don't understand exactly how your matrix must be (you should put a picture with a number in each cell of the matrix, it would be more clear). Ignasi, in his answer seems to have understand the question in the same way as me.

Comment: Thank you. The picture is updated. I appreciate your assistance and concern.

Comment: I have modified my answer :-)

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thank you for your generous help, Mr. Pantigny. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

With package [`easybmat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) you can add paths to your matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}

\[P=
\left[
\begin{BMAT}{ccccccc|c}{cccccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0
\addpath{(0,2,4)rrrrrrr}
\addpath{(0,3,4)rrrrrr}
\addpath{(0,4,4)rrrrr}
\addpath{(0,5,4)rrrr}
\addpath{(0,6,4)rrr}
\addpath{(2,7,4)dd}
\addpath{(3,7,4)ddd}
\addpath{(4,7,4)dddd}
\addpath{(5,7,4)ddddd}
\addpath{(6,7,4)dddddd}

\end{BMAT}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your assistance, Mr. Ignasi. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

```
\newcommand{\xx}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}

\[
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
     &     & & & & & \\
\cline{1-2}
     &     & & & & & \\
\cline{1-3}
\xx{}&     & & & & & \\
\cline{1-4}
\xx{}&\xx{}& & & & &\\
\cline{1-5}
Remainder left as exercise to the reader
\end{array}
\right]
\]
```

The `\xx` macro is a shortcut to reduce the amount of typing for each cell we want to drop the vertical bars in those cells that don't need them. Of course, if you don't need to fill each cell of the matrix, you could write, e.g., `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}` in place of `\xx{}&\xx{}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is inspirational